# Row grouping using two columns

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I was trying to group rows in a datatable but the whole thing is acting weirdly...

I'm using primefaces/jsf and I need to group rows by TWO fields so I came up with a simple solution: sorting by those two fields and then grouping by the first one. Not the sharpest idea but *maybe* it could work.

When I proceeded to put down some HTML I discovered that it doesnt work as expected: using expandableRowGroups= "true" on the datatable and putting the columns/column into the `<p:headerRow>` results in the first column AFTER being used as the header... and I can't really get where I'm messing things up... maybe sorting and grouping together isn't that brilliant?!

The only solution I found is to use an empty `<p:column>` inside the `<p:headerRow>` but, again, the only outcome is that ONLY the FIRST column after the closing tag is used as the header...

Long story short: I need to group rows by TWO columns...

**UPDATE:** using TWO dummy columns inside  forces the datatable to group rows using the TWO columns after ... what is happening here?!

This is the datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" var="user"
                value="#{userBean.userList}"
                widgetVar="tbl" filterEvent="enter"
                paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters}"
                paginator="true" rows="20"
                emptyMessage="#{msg['userMsg.noUser']}" reflow="true"
                sortBy="CONCAT(#{user.surname}, '', #{user.name})"
                sortOrder="ASCENDING" expandableRowGroups="true"
                rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                style="margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px;display:block;"
                rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'first-row' : 'second-row-light'}"
                editable="true">

                <p:headerRow>
                <p:column width="8%" class="centered">
                    <h:outputText value="-" />
                </p:column>
                </p:headerRow>

                <p:column width="8%" filterBy="#{user.surname}"
                    headerText="#{msg['userMsg.surname']}"
                    sortBy="#{user.surname}" class="centered">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.surname}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column width="8%" filterBy="#{user.name}"
                    headerText="#{msg['userMsg.name']}"
                    sortBy="#{user.name}" class="centered">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column width="8%" filterBy="#{user.id}"
                    headerText="#{msg['userMsg.id']}"
                    sortBy="#{user.id}" class="centered">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: instead of '(possible) bug', please state what happens in your title and what you expect.

Comment: And please post version info.

Comment: and what is this info? On a side note: could you please try to help me instead of trying only to "format" my question? :D

Comment: Instead of 'complaining', take a good look of what I am doing. I'm making your quesion better so it is easier for others (or me) to help. My next comment (should have posted that immediately) is to post an [mcve] (see [ask]), I cannot try to reproduce with the given code nor do I want to write it myself. If the answer was directly known, I would have given suggestions in the comment or post it as an answer, If it is not, we need more info. Do I need to try to reproduce with PF 5.0? Then I won't and I'd suggest to try a newer version. If you are using 6.2 then ok, So PF version please...Cheers.

Comment: I'm not complaining. I'm grateful for what you have done/are doing. I was trying to be sarcastic ;)

Comment: For me as a non-native English speaker, written sarcasm is sometimes hard to detect. The first sentence being _"and what is this info?"_ sort of did not help. (I noticed the smile but lots op people actually 'complain' due not not understanding 'good questions', being on a 'dealine' etc, so its hard)

Comment: my fault. Sorry.

Comment: No problem... Lets get back to the real issue... Version info? [mcve]? But I think the only thing that could help is changing the sourcecode...